# Changing the default gateway, multiple NICs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have Ubuntu 13.10 (kernel 3.11.0-19-generic). On startup, the network configurations are as follows:

```
dor@ubuntu:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:37:e6:4c:ca:0a  
          inet addr:10.1.0.102  Bcast:10.1.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4637:e6ff:fe4c:ca0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:68789 (68.7 KB)  TX bytes:12907 (12.9 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe600000-fe620000 

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:5e:50:cf:1e  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8485 (8.4 KB)  TX bytes:8485 (8.4 KB)

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:0b:6d:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe0b:6d1c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fc00::215:17ff:fe0b:6d1c/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4062 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:15981 (15.9 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fe540000-fe560000 

dor@ubuntu:~$ sudo route -n
[sudo] password for dor: 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p4p1
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 em1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 p4p1
```

The gateway to the internet is 10.1.0.1. So I manually execute the following:

```
dor@ubuntu:~$ sudo route del default
dor@ubuntu:~$ sudo route add default gw 10.1.0.1
```

This is how I manage to get to the internet.
But instead of doing this everytime manually, how do I make this *permanent*?

The content of `/etc/network/interfaces` (deleted some of the commented lines):

```
dor@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1

iface eth5 inet static
     address 10.90.90.91
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 10.90.90.90

iface em1 inet static
     address 10.1.0.102
     netmask 255.255.248.0
     gateway 10.1.0.1
```

I've read the manual of `interfaces` and `route` for so many times and many google results but can't figure this out. Thank you.

---

**Edit #1, 17 Apr 2014 12:11 UTC:**
(response to the responder *Sobrique*)

I've edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to have the following content:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
#iface em1 inet dhcp

iface eth5 inet static
     address 10.90.90.91
     netmask 255.255.255.0
#     gateway 10.90.90.90

iface p4p1 inet static
     address 192.168.1.32
     netmask 255.255.255.0
#     gateway 192.168.1.22

iface em1 inet static
     address 10.1.0.102
     netmask 255.255.248.0
     gateway 10.1.0.1
```

Now there's an internet access immediately upon startup, without having to execute any command.
The problem is that I don't have access to the network `192.168.1.X`.
Earlier there was an access. How can I fix this? Some data:

```
dor@ubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 em1
dor@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:37:e6:4c:ca:0a
          inet addr:10.1.0.102  Bcast:10.1.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4637:e6ff:fe4c:ca0a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:329 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2752089 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:43904 (43.9 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe600000-fe620000

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:5e:50:cf:1e
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8463 (8.4 KB)  TX bytes:8463 (8.4 KB)

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:0b:6d:1c
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fe540000-fe560000
```

---

**Edit #2, 20 Apr 2014 08:05 UTC:**

Eventually I've edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to have the following configurations:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet dhcp

auto eth5
iface eth5 inet static
     address 10.90.90.91
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     up route add -net 10.90.90.0/24 dev eth5

auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
     address 192.168.1.32
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev p4p1
```

And it worked! See:

```
dor@ubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 em1
10.90.90.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth5
10.90.90.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth5
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
```

The only problem is having those duplicates. But it doesn't interfere with anything, it still works.

---

**Edit #3, 20 Apr 2014 09:57 UTC:**

Indeed as I suspected, the duplicates were caused from the commands such as:

```
up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev p4p1
```

So I removed them. Now everything's perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the mistake here, is that you've got multiple default gateways configured in your config file. It doesn't work that way - it's a default, in that any traffic which doesn't have a *known* route gets sent there for passing on (in the expectation that it'll know, or have it's own default). But it's *not* tied to a particular interface explicitly - implicitly there will be interfaces that can reach the default gateway, but others that cannot.

So I would imagine what you need to do is remove your 'gateway' lines, and add in the single one you want - ideally in the right interface stanza, but I don't actually think it should matter.

Comment: But the interface `p4p1` isn't configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so why does Linux set a default gateway for it? Without setting a gateway, how would I be able to ping to the gateway for each interface?

Comment: Linux isn't setting a default gateway for that interface. It's setting a default gateway for the whole system. Because you've got two in `interfaces` you're doing it twice. (And one will probably be overwritin the other). A gateway is purely a system that's reachable by the local host, that will forward packets onwards.

Comment: Now I can't access the network `192.168.1.X`; Plz see my 1st edit.

Comment: Your interface - p4p1 - doesn't have an IP set any more. Which is why. What error did you get when it started up?

Comment: There was no error upon startup. Even when executing `sudo ifconfig p4p1 up`, there's no error message. On this case, `ifconfig -a` shows that the interface got 3 IPv6 addresses (2 of them have scope:global and the other has scope:link)